# Adding Wordpress site to Symfony2 (route)

Tags: symfony, routes

I have done the following steps:

1.) Extracted the latest version of Wordpress to the src folder of Symfony2

2.) Sort out routing (I currently have an issue with this.  See below)

I would like to add Wordpress to my site that is currently built using Symfony2.  The problem is that all the routes that symfony uses require a controller to be used.  However all I want to do is that whenever a user goes to www.example/newsblog he will see the wordpress site (that means it just loads up the Wordpress/index.php file)

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of searching I've finally got the answer.  All that I needed to do was add the following to my Virtual Host:

```
Alias /blog /home/john/development/phoenix/src/web/Wordpress
<Directory /home/john/development/phoenix/src/web/Wordpress>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

That way I could view my main website at www.example.com (which was hosted at /home/john/development/phoenix/src/web) as well as view the Wordpress part of the site at www.example.com/blog (which was hosted at 
/home/john/development/phoenix/src/web/Wordpress)